# Get nouislider to step down from 10 to 1 left to right

Tags: nouislider

The various examples of nouislider show sliders that go from a minimum on the left to a maximum on the right.  We now have a requirement to have the maximum on the left and for the slider to step down to the minimum.  I was just wondering if anyone had managed to get nouislider to do this succesfully?  I appreciate that the idea is somewhat daft, but I need to explore whether it's possible before I go back and say that.

Tried this:

```
            $(".custom-slider").each(function () {
                var slider = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' div.ui-slider-handle');

                let sliderDiv = slider[0];          

                //Configure the slider control
                let scaleValues = [];
                let scaleDensity = 1;

                //scaleValues = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
                scaleValues = [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0];
                scaleDensity = 10;

                sliderDiv.style.width = "100%";

                noUiSlider.create(sliderDiv, {
                    start: [0],
                    connect: true,
                    range: {
                        'min': 10,
                        'max': 0
                    },
                    step: -1,
                    pips: {
                        mode: 'positions',
                        values: scaleValues,
                        density: scaleDensity
                    }
                });
```

working on this html:

```
        <div>
            <div class="custom-slider-container">

                <div id="slider" class="custom-slider" runat="server">
                    <div class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have to say I didn't think this would work and it hasn't.  I get a slider displayed, with no pip labels and returning a NaN for each pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`direction` option](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-direction) to invert the slider direction.

```
noUiSlider.create(sliderDiv, {
    start: 20,
    direction: 'rtl', // right to left
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
});
```